# Hover slider Effect with Jquery não funciona

Tags: html, jquery, css, html5, css3

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação web utilizando html,css,Jquery e coloquei uma animação assim na minha aplicação.

[link com exemplo de que como queria na minha aplicação](https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/HoverSlideEffect/)

Mas ao passar o mouse por cima das imagens a animação não funciona e não troca as imagens como no link em que passei como exemplo.

```js
$(function() {
  //custom animations to use
  //in the transitions
  var animations = ['right', 'left', 'top', 'bottom', 'rightFade', 'leftFade', 'topFade', 'bottomFade'];
  var total_anim = animations.length;
  //just change this to one of your choice
  var easeType = 'swing';
  //the speed of each transition
  var animSpeed = 450;
  //caching
  var $hs_container = $('#hs_container');
  var $hs_areas = $hs_container.find('.hs_area');

  //first preload all images
  $hs_images = $hs_container.find('img');
  var total_images = $hs_images.length;
  var cnt = 0;
  $hs_images.each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $('<img/>').load(function() {
      ++cnt;
      if (cnt == total_images) {
        $hs_areas.each(function() {
          var $area = $(this);
          //when the mouse enters the area we animate the current
          //image (random animation from array animations),
          //so that the next one gets visible.
          //"over" is a flag indicating if we can animate 
          //an area or not (we don't want 2 animations 
          //at the same time for each area)
          $area.data('over', true).bind('mouseenter', function() {
            if ($area.data('over')) {
              $area.data('over', false);
              //how many images in this area?
              var total = $area.children().length;
              //visible image
              var $current = $area.find('img:visible');
              //index of visible image
              var idx_current = $current.index();
              //the next image that's going to be displayed.
              //either the next one, or the first one if the current is the last
              var $next = (idx_current == total - 1) ? $area.children(':first') : $current.next();
              //show next one (not yet visible)
              $next.show();
              //get a random animation
              var anim = animations[Math.floor(Math.random() * total_anim)];
              switch (anim) {
                //current slides out from the right
                case 'right':
                  $current.animate({
                      'left': $current.width() + 'px'
                    },
                    animSpeed,
                    easeType,
                    function() {
                      $current.hide().css({
                        'z-index': '1',
                        'left': '0px'
                      });
                      $next.css('z-index', '9999');
                      $area.data('over', true);
                    });
                  break;
                  //current slides out from the left
                case 'left':
                  $current.animate({
                      'left': -$current.width() + 'px'
                    },
                    animSpeed,
                    easeType,
                    function() {
                      $current.hide().css({
                        'z-index': '1',
                        'left': '0px'
                      });
                      $next.css('z-index', '9999');
                      $area.data('over', true);
                    });
                  break;
                  //current slides out from the top 
                case 'top':
                  $current.animate({
                      'top': -$current.height() + 'px'
                    },
                    animSpeed,
                    easeType,
                    function() {
                      $current.hide().css({
                        'z-index': '1',
                        'top': '0px'
                      });
                      $next.css('z-index', '9999');
                      $area.data('over', true);
                    });
                  break;
                  //current slides out from the bottom 
                case 'bottom':
                  $current.animate({
                      'top': $current.height() + 'px'
                    },
                    animSpeed,
                    easeType,
                    function() {
                      $current.hide().css({
                        'z-index': '1',
                        'top': '0px'
                      });
                      $next.css('z-index', '9999');
                      $area.data('over', true);
                    });
                  break;
                  //current slides out from the right and fades out
                case 'rightFade':
                  $current.animate({
                      'left': $current.width() + 'px',
                      'opacity': '0'
                    },
                    animSpeed,
                    easeType,
                    function() {
                      $current.hide().css({
                        'z-index': '1',
                        'left': '0px',
                        'opacity': '1'
                      });
                      $next.css('z-index', '9999');
                      $area.data('over', true);
                    });
                  break;
                  //current slides out from the left and fades out 
                case 'leftFade':
                  $current.animate({
                      'left': -$current.width() + 'px',
                      'opacity': '0'
                    },
                    animSpeed,
                    easeType,
                    function() {
                      $current.hide().css({
                        'z-index': '1',
                        'left': '0px',
                        'opacity': '1'
                      });
                      $next.css('z-index', '9999');
                      $area.data('over', true);
                    });
                  break;
                  //current slides out from the top and fades out 
                case 'topFade':
                  $current.animate({
                      'top': -$current.height() + 'px',
                      'opacity': '0'
                    },
                    animSpeed,
                    easeType,
                    function() {
                      $current.hide().css({
                        'z-index': '1',
                        'top': '0px',
                        'opacity': '1'
                      });
                      $next.css('z-index', '9999');
                      $area.data('over', true);
                    });
                  break;
                  //current slides out from the bottom and fades out 
                case 'bottomFade':
                  $current.animate({
                      'top': $current.height() + 'px',
                      'opacity': '0'
                    },
                    animSpeed,
                    easeType,
                    function() {
                      $current.hide().css({
                        'z-index': '1',
                        'top': '0px',
                        'opacity': '1'
                      });
                      $next.css('z-index', '9999');
                      $area.data('over', true);
                    });
                  break;
                default:
                  $current.animate({
                      'left': -$current.width() + 'px'
                    },
                    animSpeed,
                    easeType,
                    function() {
                      $current.hide().css({
                        'z-index': '1',
                        'left': '0px'
                      });
                      $next.css('z-index', '9999');
                      $area.data('over', true);
                    });
                  break;
              }
            }
          });
        });

        //when clicking the hs_container all areas get slided
        //(just for fun...you would probably want to enter the site
        //or something similar)
        $hs_container.bind('click', function() {
          $hs_areas.trigger('mouseenter');
        });
      }
    }).attr('src', $this.attr('src'));
  });


});
```

```css
.hs_container{
position:relative;
width: 77%;
height:471px;
overflow:hidden;
clear:both;
border:2px solid #fff;
cursor:pointer;
-moz-box-shadow:1px 1px 3px #222;
-webkit-box-shadow:1px 1px 3px #222;
box-shadow:1px 1px 3px #222;
left: 16%;
margin-top:2%;
}


.hs_container .hs_area{
position:absolute;
overflow:hidden;
width: 222%;
}
.hs_area img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  display:none;
}


.hs_area img.hs_visible{
display:block;
z-index:9999;
 
}



.hs_area1{
border-right:2px solid #fff;
 
}
.hs_area4, .hs_area5{
border-top:2px solid #fff;
}
.hs_area4{
border-right:2px solid #fff;
}
.hs_area3{
border-top:2px solid #fff;
}
.hs_area1{
width:449px;
height:334px;
top:0px;
left:0px;
}
.hs_area2{
width:451px;
height:165px;
top:0px;
left:451px;
}
.hs_area3{
width:451px;
height:167px;
top:165px;
left:451px;
}
.hs_area4{
width:192px;
height:135px;
top:334px;
left:0px;
}
.hs_area5{
width:708px;
height:135px;
top:334px;
left:194px;
  position:relative;
}
.hs_area6{
 width:18%;
height:135px;
top:334px;
left:50.3%;
   position:relative;
}
.hs_area7{
 width:18%;
height:335px;
top:0px;
left:50.3%;
   position:relative;
}
#bolo_fuba_animacao{
width:18%;
left: 5.2%;
  

}
```

```html
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<script src="js/modernizr.custom.js"></script>
<script src="js/cufon-yui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/Cantarell.font.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


  <div id="hs_container" class="hs_container">
     <div class="hs_area hs_area1">
  <img class="hs_visible" src="https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/HoverSlideEffect/images/area1/1.jpg" alt="" />
  <img src="https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/HoverSlideEffect/images/area1/2.jpg" alt="" />
  <img src="https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/HoverSlideEffect/images/area1/3.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
<div class="hs_area hs_area2">
  <img class="hs_visible" src="https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/HoverSlideEffect/images/area2/1.jpg" alt="" />
  <img src="https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/HoverSlideEffect/images/area2/2.jpg" alt="" />
  <img src="https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/HoverSlideEffect/images/area2/3.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
<div class="hs_area hs_area3">
  <img class="hs_visible" src="https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/HoverSlideEffect/images/area3/1.jpg" alt="" />
  <img src="https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/HoverSlideEffect/images/area3/2.jpg" alt="" />
  <img src="https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/HoverSlideEffect/images/area3/3.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
<div class="hs_area hs_area4">
  <img class="hs_visible" src="https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/HoverSlideEffect/images/area4/1.jpg" alt="" />
  <img src="https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/HoverSlideEffect/images/area4/2.jpg" alt="" />
  <img src="https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/HoverSlideEffect/images/area4/3.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
<div class="hs_area hs_area5">
  <img class="hs_visible" src="https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/HoverSlideEffect/images/area5/1.jpg" alt="" />
  <img src="https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/HoverSlideEffect/images/area5/2.jpg" alt="" />
  <img src="https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/HoverSlideEffect/images/area5/3.jpg" alt="" />
</div>


<div class="hs_area hs_area6">
  <img class="hs_visible" src="https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/HoverSlideEffect/images/area5/1.jpg" alt=""  id="bolo_fuba_animacao"/>
  <img src="https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/HoverSlideEffect/images/area6/2.jpg" alt="" id="bolo_fuba_animacao"/>
  <img src="https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/HoverSlideEffect/images/area6/3.jpg" alt="" id="bolo_fuba_animacao"/>
</div>



<div class="hs_area hs_area7">
  <img class="hs_visible" src="https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/HoverSlideEffect/images/area5/1.jpg" alt="" id="bolo_fuba_animacao" />
  <img src="https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/HoverSlideEffect/images/area7/2.jpg" alt="" id="bolo_fuba_animacao"/>
  <img src="https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/HoverSlideEffect/images/area7/3.jpg" alt="" id="bolo_fuba_animacao"/>
</div>
  </div>
```

Sem passar o mouse por cima das imagens da area 6 e 7 , área 6 bolo de cima, área 7 bolo de baixo.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A após eu passsar o mouse por cima da área 6 bolo de cima, área 7 bolo de baixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

UPDATE 
Ao tirar o width:200% o erro persistiu

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Tente editar sua publicação colocando todos os scripts usados. Incluindo o link cdn das bibliotecas externas

Comment: pronto, coloquei todas as bibliotecas externas do js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema está na linha `var $current = $area.find('img:visible');`. Quando você faz isso, ele vai pegar todas as imagens que estão visíveis, porém, todas as imagens estão visíveis *(como está uma sobre a outra dá impressão que não)*.

Para corrigir esse erro você deve ocultar as imagens que **não** possuem a classe `hs_visible`. Para isso basta adicionar o CSS abaixo:

```
.hs_area img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  display:none
}
```

**Exemplo completo:**

```js
$(function() {
  //custom animations to use
  //in the transitions
  var animations = ['right', 'left', 'top', 'bottom', 'rightFade', 'leftFade', 'topFade', 'bottomFade'];
  var total_anim = animations.length;
  //just change this to one of your choice
  var easeType = 'swing';
  //the speed of each transition
  var animSpeed = 450;
  //caching
  var $hs_container = $('#hs_container');
  var $hs_areas = $hs_container.find('.hs_area');

  //first preload all images
  $hs_images = $hs_container.find('img');
  var total_images = $hs_images.length;
  var cnt = 0;
  $hs_images.each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $('<img/>').load(function() {
      ++cnt;
      if (cnt == total_images) {
        $hs_areas.each(function() {
          var $area = $(this);
          //when the mouse enters the area we animate the current
          //image (random animation from array animations),
          //so that the next one gets visible.
          //"over" is a flag indicating if we can animate 
          //an area or not (we don't want 2 animations 
          //at the same time for each area)
          $area.data('over', true).bind('mouseenter', function() {
            if ($area.data('over')) {
              $area.data('over', false);
              //how many images in this area?
              var total = $area.children().length;
              //visible image
              var $current = $area.find('img:visible');
              //index of visible image
              var idx_current = $current.index();
              //the next image that's going to be displayed.
              //either the next one, or the first one if the current is the last
              var $next = (idx_current == total - 1) ? $area.children(':first') : $current.next();
              //show next one (not yet visible)
              $next.show();
              //get a random animation
              var anim = animations[Math.floor(Math.random() * total_anim)];
              switch (anim) {
                //current slides out from the right
                case 'right':
                  $current.animate({
                      'left': $current.width() + 'px'
                    },
                    animSpeed,
                    easeType,
                    function() {
                      $current.hide().css({
                        'z-index': '1',
                        'left': '0px'
                      });
                      $next.css('z-index', '9999');
                      $area.data('over', true);
                    });
                  break;
                  //current slides out from the left
                case 'left':
                  $current.animate({
                      'left': -$current.width() + 'px'
                    },
                    animSpeed,
                    easeType,
                    function() {
                      $current.hide().css({
                        'z-index': '1',
                        'left': '0px'
                      });
                      $next.css('z-index', '9999');
                      $area.data('over', true);
                    });
                  break;
                  //current slides out from the top 
                case 'top':
                  $current.animate({
                      'top': -$current.height() + 'px'
                    },
                    animSpeed,
                    easeType,
                    function() {
                      $current.hide().css({
                        'z-index': '1',
                        'top': '0px'
                      });
                      $next.css('z-index', '9999');
                      $area.data('over', true);
                    });
                  break;
                  //current slides out from the bottom 
                case 'bottom':
                  $current.animate({
                      'top': $current.height() + 'px'
                    },
                    animSpeed,
                    easeType,
                    function() {
                      $current.hide().css({
                        'z-index': '1',
                        'top': '0px'
                      });
                      $next.css('z-index', '9999');
                      $area.data('over', true);
                    });
                  break;
                  //current slides out from the right and fades out
                case 'rightFade':
                  $current.animate({
                      'left': $current.width() + 'px',
                      'opacity': '0'
                    },
                    animSpeed,
                    easeType,
                    function() {
                      $current.hide().css({
                        'z-index': '1',
                        'left': '0px',
                        'opacity': '1'
                      });
                      $next.css('z-index', '9999');
                      $area.data('over', true);
                    });
                  break;
                  //current slides out from the left and fades out 
                case 'leftFade':
                  $current.animate({
                      'left': -$current.width() + 'px',
                      'opacity': '0'
                    },
                    animSpeed,
                    easeType,
                    function() {
                      $current.hide().css({
                        'z-index': '1',
                        'left': '0px',
                        'opacity': '1'
                      });
                      $next.css('z-index', '9999');
                      $area.data('over', true);
                    });
                  break;
                  //current slides out from the top and fades out 
                case 'topFade':
                  $current.animate({
                      'top': -$current.height() + 'px',
                      'opacity': '0'
                    },
                    animSpeed,
                    easeType,
                    function() {
                      $current.hide().css({
                        'z-index': '1',
                        'top': '0px',
                        'opacity': '1'
                      });
                      $next.css('z-index', '9999');
                      $area.data('over', true);
                    });
                  break;
                  //current slides out from the bottom and fades out 
                case 'bottomFade':
                  $current.animate({
                      'top': $current.height() + 'px',
                      'opacity': '0'
                    },
                    animSpeed,
                    easeType,
                    function() {
                      $current.hide().css({
                        'z-index': '1',
                        'top': '0px',
                        'opacity': '1'
                      });
                      $next.css('z-index', '9999');
                      $area.data('over', true);
                    });
                  break;
                default:
                  $current.animate({
                      'left': -$current.width() + 'px'
                    },
                    animSpeed,
                    easeType,
                    function() {
                      $current.hide().css({
                        'z-index': '1',
                        'left': '0px'
                      });
                      $next.css('z-index', '9999');
                      $area.data('over', true);
                    });
                  break;
              }
            }
          });
        });

        //when clicking the hs_container all areas get slided
        //(just for fun...you would probably want to enter the site
        //or something similar)
        $hs_container.bind('click', function() {
          $hs_areas.trigger('mouseenter');
        });
      }
    }).attr('src', $this.attr('src'));
  });


});
```

```css
.hs_container {
  position: relative;
  width: 87%;
  height: 471px;
  overflow: hidden;
  clear: both;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #222;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #222;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #222;
  left: 9%;
}

.hs_container .hs_area {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 222%;
}

.hs_area img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  display:none
}

.hs_area img.hs_visible {
  display: block;
  z-index: 9999;
}

.hs_area1 {
  border-right: 2px solid #fff;
}

.hs_area4,
.hs_area5 {
  border-top: 2px solid #fff;
}

.hs_area4 {
  border-right: 2px solid #fff;
}

.hs_area3 {
  border-top: 2px solid #fff;
}

.hs_area1 {
  width: 449px;
  height: 334px;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}

.hs_area2 {
  width: 451px;
  height: 165px;
  top: 0px;
  left: 451px;
}

.hs_area3 {
  width: 451px;
  height: 167px;
  top: 165px;
  left: 451px;
}

.hs_area4 {
  width: 192px;
  height: 135px;
  top: 334px;
  left: 0px;
}

.hs_area5 {
  width: 708px;
  height: 135px;
  top: 334px;
  left: 194px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">


  <div id="hs_container" class="hs_container">
    <div class="hs_area hs_area1">
      <img class="hs_visible" src="https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/HoverSlideEffect/images/area1/1.jpg" alt="" />
      <img src="https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/HoverSlideEffect/images/area1/2.jpg" alt="" />
      <img src="https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/HoverSlideEffect/images/area1/3.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="hs_area hs_area2">
      <img class="hs_visible" src="https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/HoverSlideEffect/images/area2/1.jpg" alt="" />
      <img src="https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/HoverSlideEffect/images/area2/2.jpg" alt="" />
      <img src="https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/HoverSlideEffect/images/area2/3.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="hs_area hs_area3">
      <img class="hs_visible" src="https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/HoverSlideEffect/images/area3/1.jpg" alt="" />
      <img src="https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/HoverSlideEffect/images/area3/2.jpg" alt="" />
      <img src="https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/HoverSlideEffect/images/area3/3.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="hs_area hs_area4">
      <img class="hs_visible" src="https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/HoverSlideEffect/images/area4/1.jpg" alt="" />
      <img src="https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/HoverSlideEffect/images/area4/2.jpg" alt="" />
      <img src="https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/HoverSlideEffect/images/area4/3.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="hs_area hs_area5">
      <img class="hs_visible" src="https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/HoverSlideEffect/images/area5/1.jpg" alt="" />
      <img src="https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/HoverSlideEffect/images/area5/2.jpg" alt="" />
      <img src="https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/HoverSlideEffect/images/area5/3.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
  </div>
```

> Outro ponto é que as imagens que **não** possuem a classe `hs_visible`, provavelmente, estão na pasta errada.

Comment: quando eu adiciono o css que você me passou  todas as imagens somem , editei a pergunta e coloquei a imagem com o erro

Comment: @User1999 é que você está adicionando no final da página. Você **deve** adicionar antes da linha `.hs_area img.hs_visible {`

Comment: era isso mesmo obrigado

Comment: funcionou o exemplo que você me passou, mas fiz algumas alterações em que adicionei uma area6 e area7 com algumas imagens e  quando passo o mouse por cima das imagens da area 6 ou 7 , as imagens com animação elas passam por cima das imagens do lado editei a pergunta e coloquei o novo código e uma imagem com o erro

Comment: Remova o `width: 222%;` da classe `.hs_container .hs_area`

Comment: removi o width: 222%; da classe .hs_container .hs_area mas as imagens da area 6 e area7 diminuíram  e continuaram uma em cima das outras atualizei a pergunta e coloquei a imagem com o erro